# Login to Azure AD using Biometric authentication

Tags: android, react-native, single-sign-on, openid-connect

Can i login to azure AD using biometric authentication from mobile?
I want to implement SSO feature but instead of enter email and password the user can use biometric authentication

Comment: Hi did you ever figure out a solution to this?